# database design

Tags: database-design, search

i'm developing web search tool for college search...

tool should support to search college...
                1. by course
                2. by fees
                3. by name

is there i have to follow any database algorithm to make my search so efficient... is it must i have to use datamining technique when college data grows so big... please guide me... i really welcome all of your suggestions...

Comment: What are "database algorithms"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set aside your question is barely legible, here's the thing.

Data mining is not just searching. It's a whole different thing, which is not applicable to the task as you defined it. What you need is a sane database schema (3rd normal form) with proper indexes (plus some denormalization if required) and, possibly, external full-text search tool (think Lucene).

Comment: Your first sentence is barely readable unless you already know what you're trying to say.